# Pluralize in Python without pluralize function

Tags: python, string, function

I'm attempting to write a function that would pluralize all the words of a user's input. These are the criteria I want to worry about about:

- if the word ends in a 'y' preceded by a vowel (a,e,i,o,u), add 's';
  e.g. monkey -> monkeys
- if the word ends in 'y' not preceded by a
  vowel, remove the 'y' and add 'ies', e.g. fly -> flies
- if the word ends in 'o','ch', 's', 'sh', 'x', or 'z' then add 'es' otherwise,
  just add 's'

For example, if the user enters: 'monkey elephant potato porch fly button fish fox buzz', then the output should be 'monkeys elephants potatoes porches flies buttons fishes foxes buzzes'

Here's what I have so far:

```
#Ask for user input
word = input("What would you like to convert to plural?: ")

#Separate words in input into list
splitstring = word.split()
conversionlist = list(splitstring)
##list check
#print(conversionlist)


def plural(splitstring):
    #For every single word in string
    for split in conversionlist:
        #If vowel before y (endswith only takes 3 arguments)
        if split.endswith('ay','ey','iy') or split.endswith('oy','uy'):
            return split + 's'
        #If not a vowel before y
        if split.endswith('y') and not (split.endswith('ay','ey','iy') or split.endswith('oy','uy')):
            #Remove the y and append the appropriate ending
            return split[:-1] + 'ies'
        #o, ch, s, sh, x, or z endings
        if split.endswith('o') or split.endswith('ch') or split.endswith('s') or split.endswith('sh') or split.endswith('x') or split.endswith('z'):
            return split + 'es'
        #general case
        else:
            return split + 's'

plural(splitstring)

#Append all converted plurals into singular list and print output
totalplural = " ".join(plural(splitstring))
print(totalplural)
```

Right now I'm getting a "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method" on line 25. Any thoughts on how I could modify the code to get it to do what I want it to do?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do:

```
split.endswith('ay','ey','iy')
```

The `endswith` method only accepts a single string argument, optionally followed by `start` and `end` indices.  Instead, you can test each suffix individually, or you can avoid `endswith` and instead do:

```
split[-2:] in ('ay', 'ey', 'iy')
```

which will do what you want.

Update:  You *can* have `endswith` check for multiple suffixes at once if you pass a `tuple` for the first argument.  So a better way to do this is:

```
split.endswith(('ay','ey','iy'))
```

The extra parentheses create a `tuple` that's passed as the first (and only) argument to `endswith`.  This is closer to what you wanted to do in the first place.